# Kubernetes ingress not working with .NET Web API

Tags: docker, kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

Hi StackOverflow community, I'm doing courses about Kubernetes and I was learning how to expose a .NET Web API to an external hostname. The problem is that I've followed all steps to create an NGINX deployment, the .NET deployment and the ingress. I will leave you all the files involved. And apparently, all is up and all services are linked. But when I try to access http://api.ravser.com:30000/test I never get the 200 OK it should fire.

nginx-ingress.yml: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/purulabuwo.yaml

plantmoneyapi-deployment.yml: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/guvunayoho.yaml

plantmoneyapi-service.yml: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/irotecomil.yaml

ingress.yml: https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/ojutorifeg.yaml

[image: kubectl get all]

[image: kubectl get ing]

Comment: do you call api.ravser.com from you local machine of from a container within the cluster?

Comment: I'm trying to access it outside the machine.